# Symfony - Change an entity field with calling a method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony 5 and trying to solve the following issue in a good way:

**Issue:** We have some sports classes, which have `startTime` and also `status`. We want to create a feature to change the `status` to `finished` automatically when a class has finished.
We assume that the sport classes are finished after 2 hours from the `startTime`.

We use doctrine, Symfony 5, and also we have a sportClass entity with `id`, `name`, `startTime` and `status` fields.

Do you know any good idea, where and how we should trigger updating status to `finished`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a console command and run it via cron.
In this command you can query records with `status` != "finished" and `startTime` < (new DateTime())->modify('-2 hours'). Then change a status of selected records.